# looping through multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

The following criteria does 75% of what I need. It returns employees with two or more records, one of whom is status 'R' (TBL A) and one of which is not status not in 'a','r' (TBL B).

What is the best way to loop through TBL B if the number of records on this table for a given employee is unknown?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.EMPLID, A.EMPL_RCD, B.EMPL_RCD
FROM TBL A, TBL B
WHERE A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
  AND A.EMPL_RCD != B.EMPL_RCD
  AND A.STATUS != 'A'
  AND B.STATUS = 'R'
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "loop through `TBL B`".  That doesn't sound like something done with a query.

Comment: Also please explain "one of which is *not* status *not* in 'a','r' (TBL B)", as it doesn't match up with the query in your question.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would probably help a lot here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This will get the `EMPL_REC`s with the `R` status and a corresponding `EMPL_REC` with a status that is not `A` or `R` and will do it in a single table scan (i.e. no joins):

```
SELECT EMPLID,
       R_EMPL_RCD,
       NOT_R_EMPL_RCD
FROM   (
  SELECT EMPLID,
         EMPL_RCD AS R_EMPL_RCD,
         COALESCE(
           LAG( CASE STATUS WHEN 'R' THEN NULL ELSE EMPL_RCD END )
             IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLID ORDER BY ROWID ),
           LEAD( CASE STATUS WHEN 'R' THEN NULL ELSE EMPL_RCD END )
             IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLID ORDER BY ROWID )
         ) AS NOT_R_EMPL_RCD,
         STATUS
  FROM   TBL
  WHERE  STATUS <> 'A'
) 
WHERE STATUS = 'R'
AND   NOT_R_EMPL_RCD IS NOT NULL;
```